# Grammar written using Antlr in java

Tags: antlr, grammar

I am new to this section, i want to identify two digit integers in following range [1-3][0-9]. 
i wrote it as

```
goal        : firstD secondD WS firstD secondD;     
firstD      : '1'|'2'|'3';
secondD     : '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9' ;
WS          :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();} ;
```

but this gives the MismatchedTokenException. is there anything wrong in my grammer ?

Answer (score 1):

You get a `MismatchedTokenException` because you used the `WS` rule in your `goal` rule. But this `WS` rule is being `skip`ped from the lexer. Either remove it from your `goal` rule, or remove the `{skip();}` part from `WS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your white spaces :

```
 WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
;
```

and remove WS from goal definition.